# Magento Php Upgrade : Error

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.6

When i run magento upgrade, i get the follwing error:
Im using xammp, windows. Can some assist me please>?

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Unknown filter type [phonetic] for [phonetic]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Unknown filter type [phonetic] for [phonetic]"},"status":400}
```

Answer (score 1):

what command are you using to update magento?

It should be something to the effect of:

```bash
composer require-commerce magento/product-community-edition 2.4.6-p3 --no-update
```

```
composer update
```

```
rm -rf var/cache/*
```

```
rm -rf var/page_cache
```

```
rm -rf generated/code
```

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

You situation seems to be like the following [question at stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72210945/illegal-argument-exception-reasonunknown-filter-type-phonetic-for-phonet)

```
cd /usr/share/elasticsearch
bin/elasticsearch-plugin install analysis-phonetic
bin/elasticsearch-plugin install analysis-icu
sudo service elasticsearch restart
```

Comment: I'm using the same code bin/magento setup:upgrade, this error coming after i uploaded a new theme to root folder

Comment: I tried all the commands, still the same

Comment: what happens when you remove or disable the theme and try to upgrade?

Comment: when i disable theme, it works fine. i get the follwing error in webpage now 1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Please upgrade your database: Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from the Magento root directory.
The following modules are outdated:
Smile_ElasticsuiteCatalog data: current version - none, required version - 1.6.3
Smile_ElasticsuiteCatalogRule data: current version - none, required version - 1.0.0
Smile_ElasticsuiteSwatches data: current version - none, required version - 0.0.1

Comment: see the link in my initial reply to see if that helps

Comment: its on local host!

Comment: is there a bin folder in the Program Files/Elasticsearch?

Comment: Fixed it brother! apprecite your support

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it using the following :

1. Set up plugin analysis-phonetic by the command: `bin/elasticsearch-plugin install analysis-phonetic`
2. Set up plugin analysis-icu by the command: `bin/elasticsearch-plugin install analysis-icu`

Worked perfectly

Comment: Nice to know the question did solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

> **Install Elasticsearch Plugin**

**Step-1** : Check **analysis-phonetic** and **analysis-icu** is installed or not.

```
sudo /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-plugin  list
```

**Step-2** : Go to **elasticsearch** folder for install plugin.

```
cd /usr/share/elasticsearch
```

**Step-3** : For install **analysis-phonetic** plugin

```
sudo bin/elasticsearch-plugin install analysis-phonetic
```

**Step-4** : For Install **analysis-icu** plugin

```
sudo bin/elasticsearch-plugin install analysis-icu
```

**Step-5**: For activate the install plugin

```
sudo service elasticsearch restart
```

***Note: If you already installed it and show an error, remove and reinstall it. Maybe it was fixed after that.***

```
sudo bin/elasticsearch-plugin remove analysis-phonetic

sudo bin/elasticsearch-plugin remove analysis-icu
```

Comment: Solved. Thank you